# Background picture is "blinking" when the screen orientation is changed

Tags: ios, orientation

I would like to change the background picture of my view controller, when the orientation is changed. I call my setupGUIForOrientation function in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [self setupGUIForOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    return YES;
}
```

The setupGUIForOrientation function:

```
-(void)setupGUIForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if(!background) background = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage* image = [[StorageProvider storage].imageProvider getImageForSurfaceElement:@"background"];
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        width = MIN(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
        height = MAX(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
    } else {
        width = MAX(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
        height = MIN(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
    }
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    [self.view addSubview: background];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack: background];
    [background setImage:image];
}
```

Everything is good (the image and the frame changes) except one thing: when the rotation happens, I can see the view controller's background color for one second, which is really ugly. Can I prevent it somehow? And, can I code this function on a better way? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, but you may be updating your view too early. Rather than call your method in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, have you tried doing it in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`?

I.e. making this change:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self setupGUIForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

Comment: It is too late, I can see the old picture and a "half" screen with background color before the picture changes :S

Comment: OK, then you could try willRotateToInterfaceOrientation (and use the orientation that is being passed in -- self.interfaceOrientation wouldn't be updated yet)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does the original thing :S

Comment: I have found a solution, I added this line of code: [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[[StorageProvider storage].imageProvider getImageForSurfaceElement:@"background"]]]; into the viewDidLoad method. It does not solve the problem, but it is not ugly anymore :)